# How to find stored procedure which contains given string

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have many store procedure created in my databse.
but i need to search stored procedure which contains 'welcome to' in its definition.
I can check each stored procedure by sp_helptext
I have many stored procedure So i cant check each store procedure using sp_help because its time consuming

Please help if can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use System view `SYS.SQL_MODULES` and `SYS.OBJECTS`
I have created stored procedure to find any text within any type of object

check it below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SearchFromObjects]
(
    @SearchString NVARCHAR(500) = NULL,
    @SearchObjectList VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(1000)
    SELECT @SearchObjectList = ''''+REPLACE(@SearchObjectList, ',', ''',''')+''''

    IF ISNULL(@SearchString, '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT @sqlQuery = ' SELECT SYS_OBJ.NAME AS [OBJECT_NAME],
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN SYS_OBJ.TYPE = ''P''
                                        THEN ''PROCEDURE''
                                    WHEN SYS_OBJ.TYPE = ''TR''  
                                        THEN ''TRIGGER''
                                    WHEN SYS_OBJ.TYPE = ''FN''  
                                        THEN ''SCALAR FUNCTION''
                                    WHEN SYS_OBJ.TYPE = ''TF''  
                                        THEN ''TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION''
                                    WHEN SYS_OBJ.TYPE = ''IF''  
                                        THEN ''INLINE TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION''
                                    WHEN SYS_OBJ.TYPE = ''V''   
                                        THEN ''VIEW''                               
                                END [OBJECT_TYPE]
                             FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES SYS_MOD
                             INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS SYS_OBJ ON SYS_OBJ.OBJECT_ID = SYS_MOD.OBJECT_ID
                             WHERE SYS_MOD.DEFINITION LIKE ''%'+@SearchString+'%''' +
                             CASE 
                                WHEN ISNULL(@SearchObjectList, '') <> ''
                                    THEN ' AND SYS_OBJ.TYPE IN('+@SearchObjectList+') '
                             ELSE '' END +
                             ' ORDER BY SYS_OBJ.TYPE '
    END                          

    IF(ISNULL(@SearchString, '') = '')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Error : Incorrect Syntax...!!!      '
        PRINT '                                   ' 
        PRINT '-----------------------------------'
        PRINT 'Procedure Can take two arguments   '
        PRINT '-----------------------------------'
        PRINT '[1] Search String       : string to search in object defination (Required)'
        PRINT '         Syntax      : EXEC [SearchFromObjects] ''<<String to search>>'''
        PRINT '         For Example : EXEC [SearchFromObjects] ''Welcome to'''
        PRINT '[2] Search Object type  : list of object type in which user want to search (Optional)'
        PRINT '         Syntax      : EXEC [SearchFromObjects] ''<<String to search>>'', ''<<List of object type seperated by comma>>'''
        PRINT '         For Example : EXEC [SearchFromObjects] ''Welcome to'', ''P,TR,FN,TF,IF,V'''
        PRINT '                                       ' 
        PRINT 'List of allowed object types'
        PRINT '---------------------------------------'
        PRINT ' TYPE     DESCRIPTION                  '
        PRINT '---------------------------------------'
        PRINT ' P        PROCEDURE                    '
        PRINT ' TR       TRIGGER                      '
        PRINT ' FN       SCALAR FUNCTION              '
        PRINT ' TF       TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION        '
        PRINT ' IF       INLINE TABLE-VALUED FUNCTION '
        PRINT ' V        VIEW                         '
        PRINT '---------------------------------------'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE(@sqlQuery)  
    END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON                                         
END
GO
```

Just pass two parameters 1) string ('Welcome to') and 2) Object type ('P' for procedure) then you will get the stored procedure name which contain your search string

```
EXEC [SearchFromObjects] 'Welcome to', 'P'
```

you can execute [SearchFromObjects] without any parameter to get more help

Comment: you can pass more type of objects like trigger, function as per your need

Comment: i have tested it and its very useful for me to search text from any object. thanks once again, great work :)

Comment: Can you tell me where this views are stored?

Comment: Its available at Views >> System Views under the each database

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933197(v=sql.80).aspx)**.

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE  ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%welcome to%'
       AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

or use **[`sys.sql_modules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175081.aspx)**

```
SELECT sm.object_id,
       Object_name(sm.object_id) AS object_name,
       sm.definition
FROM   sys.sql_modules AS sm
       JOIN sys.objects AS o
         ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE  type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
       AND definition LIKE'%welcome to%'
```

Comment: DownVoter can you please **comment**